# High sodium Udon noodles

Tags: pasta, sodium

I am on a low sodium diet. Does soaking noodles with too much sodium and dumping the soak water before cooking reduce the sodium level?

Answer (score 4):

While some of the sodium content will leach out of the noddle during soaking, unfortunately most of the sodium will remain. The sodium (salt) is added to the dough before the noodles are formed, making it difficult to remove most of it during cooking.

Instead, there are many brands of Udon Noodles - some will have less sodium content, or even [no sodium](https://hakubaku-usa.com/product/no-salt-japanese-udon-noodles/).

If you're feeling particularly adventurous, [you might even try making some of your own](https://steamykitchen.com/43189-homemade-udon-noodle-recipe-morimoto.html)!